# Surface plot raw data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to fit some 3D data to a function and plot it using Python.

[This tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html) describes how to plot a 3D surface but it assumes that we know the function describing the surface.

How can i import the data below and plot it using the plot_surface function (without knowing that z = x*y in this case)?

```
    x   1   2   3   4
y                   
1       1   2   3   4
2       2   4   6   8
3       3   6   9   12
4       4   8   12  16
5       5   10  15  20
```

Comment: in the tutorial, meshgrid was used to represent the x and y locations with the array values representing z.  If this is what you have shown above, then you have all the data you need

Comment: I guess my question is how do I get these values into the Z variable in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data format is not very convenient to work with, but here is a way to read in the data, ignoring the coordinates and regenerating them afterwards.

```
import io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

d = u"""    x   1   2   3   4
y                   
1       1   2   3   4
2       2   4   6   8
3       3   6   9   12
4       4   8   12  16
5       5   10  15  20"""

s = io.StringIO(d)
a = np.loadtxt(s, skiprows=2)
Z = a[:,1:] # ignore first column

x = np.arange(1,Z.shape[1]+1)
y = np.arange(1,Z.shape[0]+1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I've used jupyther to run these examples, but the plots come out looking a bit strange. Can I ask what environment you use? Completely new to Python.

Comment: This is run as a script in python 2.7, matplotlib 2.0. What does "a bit strange" mean? – [This is how it looks in jupyter for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcEwG.png).

Comment: The surface is plotted without the colored squares indicating Z value. It is shown as a single blue surface

Comment: Could it be that you're using matplotlib 1.4 or 1.5? In that case stick to the [tutorial of those versions](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html), where you'd need to use `rstride=1, cstride=1,`.